# Regex split by non-alphanumeric characters with special treatment of words with apostrophes contractions

Tags: c#, regex, text, split

I am trying to split a string using Regex in C#. I want to split it based on all non-alphanumeric characters but I would like to treat words with apostrophes as whole word when contains a contraction such as: `'d`, `'s`, `'t`.
An example should clarify what I would like to achieve. Given a sentence such as:

```
"Steve's dog is mine 'not yours' I know you'd like'it"
```

I would like to obtain the following tokens:

```
steve's, dog, is, mine, not, yours, i, know, you'd, like, it
```

At the moment I am using:

```
Regex.Split(str.ToLower(), @"[^a-zA-Z0-9_']").Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray<string>();
```

It returns:

```
steve's , dog , is , mine , 'not , yours', i , know, you'd, like'it
```

Comment: What about `the Hundred Years' War` - or `say: 'the Hundred Years' War of yours'` !? ;).

Comment: `.Select(s => s.Trim('\''))` after `Where` solves the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a half-regex-half-LINQ solution:

```
string s = "Steve's dog is mine 'not yours' I know you'd like'it";
string[] result = Regex.Matches(s, "\\w+('(s|d|t|ve|m))?")
    .Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

I try to match everything that you want to *get*, instead of the separators you want to *split by*. And then I just `Select`ed the `Value`s and turn them all into an array.

Comment: Yours won't catch: `should've` `i'm`

Comment: The op said only d s and t are needed. @linden2015

Answer (score 0):

`\w+(?:'(?![aeiou])\w+)?`

```
\w+         // 1 or more word chars
(?:         // optional uncaptured group
'           // apostrophe
(?![aeiou]) // look ahead and assert the character class doesn't match
\w+         // 1 or more word chars
)?          // end of optional group
```

- Catches: `should've`, `i'm`, `'tis`
- Doesn't catch: `rock 'n' roll`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kQVZhh/2)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I can think about it is something like this:

```
var txt = "Steve's dog is mine 'not yours' I know you'd like'it, the Hundred Years' War, I'm - they're - don't - o'clock - we've 'the Hundred Years' War of yours'";

// Finding valid `'`s and replace them temporarily to something like `_replaceMe_`
// Then replace net `'` to a blank space ` `
var osTxt = Regex.Replace(txt.ToLower(), 
    @"(?<=[^a-z]i)'(?=m[^a-z])|(?<=[a-z])'(?=([rv]e|[ds])[^a-z])|(?<=[a-z]n)'(?=t[^a-z])|(?<=[^a-z]o)'(?=(clock)?[^a-z])", 
    "_replaceMe_")
    .Replace("\'"," ");

// Now, extract words from sentence and replace `_replaceMe_` back to `'`
var words = Regex.Matches(osTxt, @"\w+")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(c=> c.Value.Replace("_replaceMe_", "\'"))
    .ToList();
```

But this will not have `'` of `Years'` in a sentence like `the Hundred Years' War`.
Also there is some other [valid situation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)) those ignored ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
 //  also covers: I've I'm She'll you're you've";

        var sen = "Steve's dog is mine 'not yours' I know you'd like'it";

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(sen, @"[^' ]+\w+\'([dstm]|ll|ve|re)|\w+"))
        {
            builder.Append(m.Value).Append(",");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(builder);

        //Steve's,dog,is,mine,not,yours,I,know,you'd,like,it,
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did it like this:

```
string phrase = "Steve's dog is mine 'not yours' I know you'd like'it";
var splittedString = Regex.Split(phrase, "[^a-zA-Z0-9']+")
    .Select(word => word.Trim('\''))
    .Where(word => word
        .Any())
    .ToArray();
```